# cannot find symbol error when create object of another class in java without extends only in windows

Tags: java, compilation

I hava 2 java files.

First one is Sample.java

Second is Sample2.java

both codes are

Sample.java

```
public class Sample{
    int Number = 1000;
}
```

Sample2.java

```
public class Sample2{
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        Sample obj = new Sample();
    }
}
```

When i compile sample2.java it shows the following error

[image]

I dont know what the problem is?. This same code run in linux. I using win 7 32 bit. is there need to change any settings in windows. My java version is 1.8.0.181.

Give me the answer to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the folder which contains Sample.class to your classpath:

```
javac -cp ./ Sample2.java
```

Comment: Fine this works. why this kind errors happen? I set environmental variables for JDk and JRE. Then why i have to give classpath for folders which contain a class file for each and every project. Any permanent solution is available for this problem?

Comment: You can set ste CLASSPATH environement variable and add all pathes you need, you can use an IDE which manage the classpath for you ...